# How to store and retrieve a dynamic listview

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, serialization, sharedpreferences

I Have 2 activities: **activity X** & **activity Y**.

**Y** sends data to **X** via an intent and **X** displays the data in a listView.

The problem I am having is saving the listView in **X** so the next time a user goes to activity **Y** and sends an intent the listView will display the last data that was send + the new data, this way the user will continue to populate the ListView .

I was thinking about saving all the data in a sqlLite database and then retrieving it and displaying the updated listView that way?

or maybe to serialize my list and save it via SharedPrefs (not sure if that would actually work,I am a really new at this)

Any suggestions and code samples would be appreciated!!!! THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a small amount of data (<5 variables) I suggest you to implement a Sharepreferences class with the methods you need (basically, put and get). For more than that, someone told me to use SQLite, but I've never used before, even if it seems easy to put in place.
Besides, these are methods useful if you want to store data even if the app is closed, and you could retrieve them after in another session. If data lives only for a session, put everything in a bundle and go back and forth with it.

Comment: There should be way more than 5 variables passed and saving all of that in shared prefs seems like its not the right thing to implement. Sending data back and forth with a bundle seems like overkill. I am starting to lean more towards the sqllite database route where data will be stored once and retrieved and displayed in the lsitview once, plus if data had to be edited it would be easier no?

Comment: Well, as I wrote, I've never used SQLite before, but everyone told me it's really easy to use it and implement it. So, for this amount of data, go straight on SQLite ;)

Answer (score 1):

well, You can use any of the

1) **sharedPreference** : for primitive data only .

2)**File storage(internal/external)** : limited size , no quert support , suitable when storing long string kind of data

3)**SQlite** : suitable for complex structure , because of query support